# Multidimensional array and addressing

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I have an issue with the multidimensional arrays. Maybe the solution is much easier.

```
int arr[2][2]; //multidimensional array
```

My simple question is: why the

arr[0][2] and arr[1][0] 
or
arr[1][2] and arr[2][0]

are on the same address in my case?
I checked this problem in Linux and Windows environment. And the issue is the same. I have checked tutorials and other sources, but no answer.

Comment: How do you check what their address is?

Comment: Are you very sure you are not getting the address of the base pointer each time?  That would be my strong guess.  Post your code used to check the addresses.

Comment: Evaluating `arr[0][2]` produces an out-of-bounds access, which has undefined behaviour. (But just taking its address is fine (`&arr[0][2]`) because that doesn't evaluate.)

Comment: You cannot use `arr[0][2]` because it is out-of-range. (`&arr[0][2]` is valid because it is just one element after the last element and it is not dereferenced)

Comment: It is normal, the multidimensionnal arrays are in fact transformed into 1 dimension arrays when you don't use pointers. Due to that, you can't use those tables with double pointers casting. [x][y] will be replaced with [x * sizeof(first_col) + y] .

Answer (score 1):

The pointer `&arr[0][2]` is the one-past-the-end pointer of the array `arr[0]`. This is the same address as that of the first element of the next array, `arr[1]`, which is `&arr[1][0]`, because arrays are laid out contiguously in memory.

`arr[2][0]` is a bit tricker: `arr[2]` is not a valid access, but `&arr[2]` is the one-past-the-end pointer of the array `arr`. But since that pointer cannot be dereferenced, it doesn't make sense to talk about `arr[2][0]`. `arr` doesn't have a third element.

Answer (score 0):

C stores multi-dimensional arrays in what is called [*row-major order*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order). In that configuration, all the data for a single row is stored in consecutive memory:

```
arr[2][2] -> r0c0, r0c1, r1c0, r1c2
```

The alternative would be *column-major order,* which places the columns consecutively.

Since you have specified the length of the row (number of cols) as 2, it follows that accessing column 2 (the third column) will compute an address that "wraps around" to the next row.

The math looks like:

```
&(arr[row][col]) 

= arr # base address
+ row * ncols * sizeof(element)
+ col * sizeof(element)

= arr + sizeof(element) * (row * ncols + col)
```

In your case, `arr[0][2]` is `arr + (0*2 + 2) * sizeof(int)`, while `arr[1][0]` is `arr + (1*2 + 0)*sizeof(int)`.

You can do similar math for the other variations.

Answer (score -1):

Array indexing is identical to pointer arithmetic (actually, the array name first is converted ("decays") to a pointer to the first element before the `[]`-operator is applied):

```
arr[r][c] <=> *(arr + r * INNER_LENGTH + c)
```

Your array has two entries per dimension. In C indexes start from `0`, so for each dimension valid indexes are `0` and `1` (i.e. `total_entries - 1`). Which makes three of your expressions suspective in the first place:

```
arr[0][2]    // [outer dimension/index][inner dimension/index]
arr[1][2]
arr[2][0]
```

We have these cases:

- Both indexes are valid: no problem.
- Only the address is taken, the element is not accessed and

  - the outer index is valid and the inner (see below) index equals the length of the inner dimension: comparison and certain address arithmetic is allowed (other constraints apply!).
  - the outer index equals the length of the outer dimension, and the inner index is `0`: The same.
- Anything else: the address is invalid and any usage (take address, dereference, etc.) invokes *undefined behaviour*.

---

What exactly goes on in memory might become a bit more clear if we use different lengths for the dimensions and have a look how the data is stored:

```
int arr[3][2];
```

This is an "array of 3 arrays of 2 `int` elements". The leftmost dimension is called the "outer", the rightmost the "inner" dimension, because of the memory layout:

```
arr[0][0]   // row 0, column 0
arr[0][1]   // row 0, column 1
arr[1][0]   // ...
arr[1][1]
arr[2][0]
arr[2][1]
```

Using the formula above, `&arr[0][2]` (`arr + 0 * 2 + 2`) will yield the same as `&arr[1][0]` (`arr + 1 * 2 + 0`), etc. Note, however, while the addresses are identical, the first version must not be dereferenced and the compiler may generate incorrect code, etc.

Answer (score -2):

Array indexing in C is similar to adding the value of the index to the address of the first element.

In the multidimensional array that you describe, you have 2 elements on each dimension: 0 and 1.  When you introduce a number larger than that, you're referencing an element outside that dimension.  Technically, this is an array out of bounds error.

The addresses break down like this:

- `arr[0][0]` - `&arr[0] + 0`
- `arr[0][1]` - `&arr[0] + 1`
- `arr[1][0]` - `&arr[0] + 2`
- `arr[1][0]` - `&arr[0] + 3`

When you write arr[0][2], you're referencing address &arr[0] + 2, which is the same as arr[1][0].  It all just pointer math, so you can work it out pretty easily once you know how it works.

Answer (score -2):

You can look in your two dimensional array as a long one dimensional array:

```
[00][01][10][11]
```

With the pointers arithmetic, another representation of this long one dimensional array is:

```
[00][01][02][03]
```

So looking in cell `[10]` is exactly the same as looking into a cell [20] in pointer arithmetic point of view.